# How to get returned properties from Expression<Func<T, object[]>> parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I'm working on a `.Net core` project targeted `.Net 5`.
I have a method that will receive a parameter his type is `Expression<Func<T , object[]>>`, inside the method I will loop on all returned properties from the expression.

**What I trie :**

```
public virtual void UpdateExcept( TEntity record, params Expression<Func<TEntity , object[]>>[] propertiesToBeExcluded )
{

   //Some logic here

    foreach ( var property in  propertiesToBeExcluded )
    {
        foreach ( var prop in property.GetMemberAccessList() )
        {
          //Here I got the property name (I think)
           var x = prop.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**In runtime I got this error:**

> ArgumentException: The expression 'x => new [] {x.CreatedBy,
> Convert(x.CreatedOn, Object)}' is not a valid member access
> expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field
> access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or
> fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'.
> (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')

**More explain:**
In reality I created this method In a repository based on `Entity framework` this method should update an `TEntity` record and ignore (do not update) some sent properties in the `propertiesToBeExcluded` sometimes I will update a record and ignore one property and in another times I will update one record and ignore many properties.

**Originale method logic I tried:**

```
public virtual void UpdateExcept( TEntity record, params Expression<Func<TEntity , object[]>>[] propertiesToBeExcluded )
{
    var entity = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    entity.Attach( record );
    Context.Entry( record ).State = EntityState.Modified;

    foreach ( var property in  propertiesToBeExcluded )
    {
        foreach ( var prop in property.GetMemberAccessList())
        {
            Context.Entry( record ).Property( prop.Name ).IsModified = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of using for this method:**

```
_studentRepository.UpdateExcept( record : student , propertiesToBeExcluded : x => new object[] {x.Picture} );
```

**Another example:**

```
_studentRepository.UpdateExcept( record : student , propertiesToBeExcluded : x => new object[] {x.CreatedOn, x.CreatedBy} );
```

**This method was in this structure:**

```
public virtual void UpdateExcept( TEntity record, params Expression<Func<TEntity , object>>[] propertiesToBeExcluded )
{
    var entity = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    entity.Attach( record );
    Context.Entry( record ).State = EntityState.Modified;

    foreach ( var property in  propertiesToBeExcluded )
    {
        Context.Entry( record ).Property( property ).IsModified = false;
    }
}
```

**Example of use for the old structure:**

```
_studentRepository.UpdateExcept( record : student , propertiesToBeExcluded : x => x.CreatedOn, x => x.CreatedBy );
```

**Why I changed from the old structure to the new:**
Cause if you notice in the old structure I have to write many times the `x`'s parameter for the `func` and I was no idea how to use it one time and return multiple properties.

[**property.GetMemberAccessList()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.expressionextensions.getmemberaccesslist?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ExpressionExtensions.GetMemberAccessList);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0)

I wish all this helped you understand the issue, **so please any help about this issue ?**

Comment: What is `property.GetMemberAccessList()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.expressionextensions.getmemberaccesslist?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ExpressionExtensions.GetMemberAccessList);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0)

Comment: Ok, now I see it. But note, this is not a standard (in fact internal) EF Core method which we are not even supposed to use, so at least you could have mentioned (or provided the link) in the question. Anyway, other than that I understand the issue.

Comment: I don't know if you understand yet or not, or if you have a solution for this issue and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification in the comments, you are trying to use [GetMemberAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.expressionextensions.getmemberaccesslist?view=efcore-5.0) which is *internal* EF Core method, not supposed to be used directly by the end user code.

But let say you don't care / ignore that warning (it's a warning, not error), then it's good to know that it doesn't support expression returning array of property accessors, but expression returning *anonymous type*, similar to many EF Core fluent APIs dealing with composite keys, multi property indexes etc. So the expected signature is single optional `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`, w/o `params` array:

```
public virtual void UpdateExcept(
    TEntity record,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> propertiesToBeExcluded = null)
{
    var entity = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    entity.Attach(record);
    Context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // The modified code
    if (propertiesToBeExcluded != null)
    {
        foreach (var property in propertiesToBeExcluded.GetMemberAccessList())
        {
            Context.Entry(record).Property(property).IsModified = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage similar to

```
x => x.CreatedOn
```

or

```
x => new { x.CreatedOn }
```

for single property, and

```
x => new { x.CreatedOn, x.CreatedBy }
```

for multiple properties.

This is all needed if you want to use that method.

---

Method signature with expression returning array of expressions (the original question) cannot use that method and requires totally different approach.

First, `Expression<Func<T, object[]>>` can be called in many ways, not involving properties at all or not directly creating array, for instance

```
x => new object[] { 1, "abc", new DateTime() }
```

or

```
x => Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => (object)i).ToArray()
```

All these are valid calls, so apparently you have to put some restriction of how this will be called. Let say the expected call is like in your examples. So the only thing you need to realize is what type of expression is the *body* of

```
x => new object[] {x.CreatedOn, x.CreatedBy}
```

lambda expression. Which you can easily see if you create such expression at compile time and examine its content with debugger at runtime.

You'll find that this expression is of type [NewArrayExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newarrayexpression?view=net-5.0) which has [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newarrayexpression?view=net-5.0) property. From here it should be straightforward - cast the body and use `Expressions` property to get a list containing `x.CreatedOn`, `x.CreatedBy` etc. from the caller.

All that with custom extension method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMemberAccessList<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object[]>> source) =>
    (source.Body is NewArrayExpression newArr ? newArr.Expressions : throw new InvalidOperationException())
    .Select(e => source.Parameters[0].MatchSimpleMemberAccess<MemberInfo>(e));
```

which is using another internal EF Core method, but could be made to not do that. Use it to implement the desired method in question.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your answer and time and your effort
Please you mentioned `propertiesToBeExcluded.Ge` where can I find the `Get` ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, it meant to be the same method you were using `GetMemberAccessList()`

Comment: **I got this error :**
`ArgumentException: The expression 'x => new [] {x.CreatedBy, Convert(x.CreatedOn, Object)}' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')`

Comment: You've probably missing the fact that with the approach from the first part of the answer you are not calling with array - no `[]`, just `new { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, you right I forgot it, now everything is working great massive thanks brother you helped me many times
thank you again